# How to chart different shifts run times in Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, charts

I have the following as an example.

```
Date    Duration    Shift
4-Dec   60          1
4-Dec   40          2
5-Dec   45          1
5-Dec   55          2
5-Dec   30          3
```

I am trying to map these either on a bar or line/scatter graph and basically have Duration be Y and Date be X and map which shift for each. I can't seem to remember how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "map which shift for each"? A label?

Comment: Sorry, still early for me :) Basically I want the Y to be Duration but yes be labels as the Shift so I can see for Dec 5 in bar graph which shift took longer for the setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom data lables like the chart below, look at the suggestions on this page: http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/05/05/change-data-labels-in-charts/

[image]